# How to inject Groovy closure variable into Spock mock predicate argument?

Tags: groovy, closures, spock

I found an interesting line in Spock interactions documentation:

http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.3/interaction_based_testing.html#_argument_constraints

last line of constraints, example with closure predicate:

```
1 * subscriber.receive({ it.size() > 3 && it.contains('a') })
```

My question is: **is there a way in Groovy to pass this predicate as variable?**

My testing environment code:

```
class Something {
   Doer doer

   Something(Doer doer) {
      this.doer = doer
   }

   boolean doSth(x) {
      if (!doer.validate(x)) throw new RuntimeException()
      true
   }
}

class Doer {
   boolean validate(int x) {
      x == 2
   }
}
```

and test code:

```
   def "some test"() {
      given:
      def d = Mock(Doer)
      def s = new Something(d)

      when:
      s.doSth(2)

      then:
      1 * d.validate({ it == 2 }) >> true
   }
```

what I would like to achieve:

```
def "some test"() {
      given:
      def d = Mock(Doer)
      def s = new Something(d)
      def myClosureVar = { ??? }

      when:
      s.doSth(2)

      then:
      1 * d.validate(myClosureVar) >> true
   }
```

Comment: I don't believe there is, I seem to recall that it needs to be in the actual definition of the test, so that spock can work it's DSL magic on it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The closure takes an argument, as indicated by `it` having a defined value. That value is the corresponding method parameter. So whatever closure you define outside of your interaction, you need to make sure that the interaction hands over that parameter to the closure, i.e. you need to create your own (small and simple) closure evaluating the outer (potentially lengthier, more complex) closure with the parameter `it`:

```groovy
1 * d.validate({ myClosureVar(it) }) >> true
```

Sorry for the repetition, but I always prefer a full [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in my answers so you can easily copy, paste, compile and run:

**Application classes:**

```groovy
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q60341734

class Doer {
  boolean validate(int x) {
    x == 2
  }
}
```

```groovy
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q60341734

class Something {
  Doer doer

  Something(Doer doer) {
    this.doer = doer
  }

  boolean doSth(x) {
    if (!doer.validate(x)) throw new RuntimeException()
    true
  }
}
```

**Spock specification:**

```groovy
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q60341734

import org.junit.Rule
import org.junit.rules.TestName
import spock.lang.Specification

class SomethingTest extends Specification {
  @Rule
  TestName testName

  def "some test"() {
    given:
    def d = Mock(Doer)
    def s = new Something(d)

    when:
    s.doSth(2)

    then:
    1 * d.validate({ println "$testName.methodName: closure parameter = $it"; it == 2 }) >> true
  }

  def "another test"() {
    given:
    def d = Mock(Doer)
    def s = new Something(d)
    def myClosureVar = { println "$testName.methodName: closure parameter = $it"; it == 2 }

    when:
    s.doSth(2)

    then:
    1 * d.validate({ myClosureVar(it) }) >> true
  }
}
```

**Console log:**

```
some test: closure parameter = 2
another test: closure parameter = 2
```

Comment: Great, it works - thank you!
Would you also be able to produce example when you gave closure returning closure of { it == 2 }, so calling the function in validate() would also make a test pass?

Comment: But that's exactly what I did! The test does pass and it does evaluate `it == 2` as its last statement, automatically making it the result. Or do I misunderstand your question?

Comment: I'd suggest to use `assert` in your closure, then you get better error reporting.

Comment: Why would I use `assert` in the closure? Nothing actually gets verified there, the closure is just a method parameter constraint. If the constraint is not met, the interaction is not to be matched and thus the result not to be stubbed, but no assertion error is to be thrown IMO.